# Taking out bits of CSVs

Tags: python, csv, pandas, glob

I am new to programming and I have a bunch of CSV files that are about 50 to 60 rows each. After an unspecified amount of rows, there is a string called 'NAME' in the second column. I want to take everything in the second column after 'NAME' and print it to a text file. I initially thought to use `pandas` and `skiprows` to do this however the problem is that each csv I run through will have 'NAME' in a different row. Also, if it helps, there is a blank line three rows before 'NAME' in every CSV.

```
header, header   
header, header                           
NUMBER,ITEM
N1,Shoe
N2,Heel
N3,Tee, random stuff
N4,Polo, random stuff
N5,Sneaker
N10,Heel
N11,Tee
...
...
...

How         
Count   17      
SORT,NAME       
H1,Thing, random stuff   
H2,WTANK        
H3,TEE2  
H4,TEE
```

I would also like to not have repeats in the text file because I will be running through around 1000 CSVs in a directory. Here is a bit of code that I started out with and is where i got stuck.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob

fns = glob.glob('*.csv') #goes through every CSV file in director
for csv in fns:
    prod_df = pd.read_csv(csv, skiprows=???)
    with open (os.path.join('out', fn), 'wb') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        test_alias = prod_df['NAME'].unique()
        w.writerow(row)
```

I know it doesn't work, and is probably not a very good bit of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Is it possible to read the given text above as is. I have not been able to get it to work:from StringIO import StringIO
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(raw),header=0,skiprows=2,sep=",") with error  C error: Expected 2 fields in line 6, saw 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `NAME` only occurs one time you could use `get_loc`

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

fn = 'out.csv'
fns = glob.glob('*.csv') #goes through every CSV file in director
colname = 'ITEM'
rowname = 'NAME'
for csv in fns:
    s = pd.read_csv(csv, usecols=[colname], squeeze=True, skiprows=7, header=0)
    row_idx = pd.Index(s).get_loc(rowname)
    sub_items = s[row_idx + 1:]
    pd.Series(sub_items.unique()).to_csv(fn, mode='a')
```

**EDIT**: Explanation

`usecols` only reads in the column you need, i.e., `ITEM`

`squeeze=True` returns a `Series`

`get_loc` returns the index of its argument

You said you wanted everything *after* `'NAME'`, so the index is `row_idx + 1`

`mode='a'` appends to a single csv file (called `out.csv`), if you want to write to *individual* csv files then you should adjust your code accordingly

Comment: In the actual CSV, the first item in the second column varies because it is usually the filename. Is there a way we can skip the header and do this? I have changed the sample a little to show this

Comment: Is there a fixed number of header rows?

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can pass `skiprows=7` to `read_csv`.

Comment: Edited again, you also have to pass `header=0` to tell `read_csv` that you want to use `'ITEM'` as the column name.

Comment: now it is saying the 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute 'to_csv'.

Comment: yep fixed, i forgot that the `unique` method returns a `numpy` array. Make sure that's okay, since you'll lose the `index` after calling `unique`.

Comment: the `unique` method seems to not be working as I got many of the same strings. Also, after running it gave me a parse error saying that header = 0 but  only 0 lines in file. Thank You so much. You have helped me a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob

fns = glob.glob('*.csv') #goes through every CSV file in director
for csv in fns:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    row_idx = (df.ITEM == 'NAME').idxmax()
    sub_items = df.ITEM[row_idx:]
    sub_items.unique().to_csv(os.path.join('out', fn))
```

Comment: The actual CSVs have more than two columns. I just simplified it here. Sorry about that