# read_table with stringIO and messy file

Tags: pandas

In a question yesterday, [Taking out bits of CSVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344887/taking-out-bits-of-csvs), I was trying to figure out how to read the text in with some variant of

```
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(raw),header=0,skiprows=2,sep=",")
```

I  was unable to get this to work. Any suggestions? Here is the data pasted again. Thanks.

```
header, header   
header, header                           
NUMBER,ITEM
N1,Shoe
N2,Heel
N3,Tee, random stuff
N4,Polo, random stuff
N5,Sneaker
N10,Heel
N11,Tee
...
...
...

How         
Count   17      
SORT,NAME       
H1,Thing, random stuff   
H2,WTANK        
H3,TEE2  
H4,TEE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Taking out bits of CSVs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344887/taking-out-bits-of-csvs)

Comment: I thought that question dealt with once the data was  in. My question focuses on getting the data in. More generally, it is about reading with an irregular file: different separators, blank lines, and needing something like fill in R.

Comment: If you are unable to get it to work you should post that on the original question page. This is a duplicate.

Comment: It would help if you could describe the Error which you get and explicitly what it is you couldn't get working (and what you have tried). I may not be a dupe, but it's not clear how it's different atm.

Comment: Using read_table template above,  I tried different seps, not using header. All resulted in the following error: pandas._parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 6, saw 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off `warn_bad_lines` and `error_bad_lines`:

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_table(StringIO(raw),header=0,skiprows=2,sep=",", warn_bad_lines=False, error_bad_lines=False)

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
              NUMBER           ITEM
0                 N1           Shoe
1                 N2           Heel
2                 N5        Sneaker
3                N10           Heel
4                N11            Tee
5                ...            NaN
6                ...            NaN
7                ...            NaN
8       How                     NaN
9   Count   17                  NaN
10              SORT    NAME       
11                H2  WTANK        
12                H3         TEE2  
13                H4            TEE
```

*Note: I think my raw string has some additional spaces from a poor copy and paste job.*

You can then drop the `NaN`s and the titles, which I think is described in the other answer:

```
df.dropna()
```