# How to use pd.read_table with StringIO file object?

Tags: python, pandas

I checked out [read_table with stringIO and messy file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383711/read-table-with-stringio-and-messy-file) but it has some stuff I can't reproduce like this raw object.  Anyways, I want to write a table to a `StringIO` file object and then open that `StringIO` file object in `pandas` with the `read_table` method but I am getting `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`.  The file I will be writing to will be too large to store in memory so I want to read it in chunks.  Using `StringIO` as a test example. Using Python 3.5.1 btw

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

#StringIO to write to
f = StringIO()

#Write to StringIO
dist = np.random.normal(100, 30, 10000)
for idx,s in enumerate(dist):
    f.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format("label_A-%d" % idx, "label_B-%d" % idx, str(s)))

#Pandas DataFrame from it
DF = pd.read_table(f,sep="\t",header=None)
#EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Comment: You have to do a `f.seek(0)` before reading to rewind back to the start.

Comment: Are you aware that pandas already includes facilities for reading from a file in chunks (see the `chunksize` parameter to, e.g., `read_csv`)?

Comment: @BrenBarn yup, that's what I'm going to use but i'm making a test file to practice it on and i wanted to use stringio to hold the test data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StringIO uses a pointer to track the current position in the stream. Once you have written all data to the stream, use `f.seek(0)` to set the pointer back to the start.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

#StringIO to write to
f = StringIO()

#Write to StringIO
dist = np.random.normal(100, 30, 10000)
for idx,s in enumerate(dist):
    f.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format("label_A-%d" % idx, "label_B-%d" % idx, str(s)))

# rewind the stream
f.seek(0)

#Pandas DataFrame from it
DF = pd.read_table(f,sep="\t",header=None)
#EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Comment: woah, that's so weird. why do you need to "rewind" it?

Comment: @O.rka, I guess it's because StringIO uses the same pointer for the position where to read next and where to insert next. So if you write, the pointer will be at the end of the content (where you would append the next line). If you want to read afterwards it assumes that all the content has already been read (before the current pointer). I agree it's not very intuitive.